# Pass Java Script function as parameter to C++ function

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I declare my object in C++

```
class Action : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ name)
public:
  Action(): QObject(0) {}
  QString name() const { return "rem"; }
  Q_INVOKABLE void getData() {};
}
```

and make it available to qml:

```
engine()->rootContext()->setContextProperty("action", new Action());
```

How to pass to getData() method **javascript function as parameter** and call this function on C++ side?

So from QML point of view it should looks like:

```
action.getData(function(data) { alert(data); });
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is possible using [QJSValue](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsvalue.html). For example:

```
//C++
Q_INVOKABLE void getData(QJSValue value) {
    if (value.isCallable()) {
        QJSValueList args;
        args << QJSValue("Hello, world!");
        value.call(args);
    }
}

//QML
action.getData(function (data){console.log(data)});
```