# Javascript waiting in QML

Tags: qml, qt5

I have two javascript functions `fun1`, `fun2` in QML, and want to execute one (`fun2`) after another (`fun1`) is finished, more precisely, how do I start `fun2()` after the `ImageReader` in `fun1` is done. `ImageReader` is a function written in C++ by inheriting `QImageProvider`, as follows:

```
function fun1(){
    ImageReader.magic(photo);
}
function fun2(){
    myImg.source = ""; 
    myImg.source = "image://ImageReader";
}
fun1();
fun2();
```

The usage scenario is that I want to process an image in C++, and when the processing is done, show it by QML Image item.

Comment: So what is your question? Don't you already execute `func2()` after `func1()` according to the code you've provided?

Comment: I'd reccomend to call them one after another.  For example like the code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42607709/javascript-waiting-in-qml). What makes you think they are not executed one after another?

Comment: I think your problem is, that `fun1()` only starts the method `ImageReader.magic(photo)` that is executed asyncronously in another thread. So your question should be: *How do I start `fun2()` after the `ImageReader` is done with his magic.* because `fun1()` might be finished before that. So `fun2()` is executed right after `fun1()` finished, but before `ImageReader.magic(photo)` is done.

Comment: Great thanks for the comments @derM, folibis. I have updated the question to make it more precise. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have control over the class `ImageReader`? If so, declare a signal, and fire it at the end of the method `magic(photo)`. Then you can connect `fun2()` to it.

Comment: Or follow the pattern of the [`Loader`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#status-prop) and other QML-Components and include a property `status` in your `ImageReader`. This comes along with the property `statusChanged`

Comment: As I know `QQuickImageProvider` doesn't inherit from `QObject` so using signals will require changes in inheritance. But I agree with @derM, that's nice way to do what you want. Another way is to pass pointer to "next" function to C++ object (ImageReader in you case). See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29455675/pass-java-script-function-as-parameter-to-c-function) question's answer to learn more.

Comment: Thanks all! It works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially you have two options on how to approach this

1. Make the asynchronous process notify about it being finished
2. Poll for the availability of the result

I would not recommend the second approach, especially in the declarative environment, so let's further look into option one.

For notification between C++ and QML/JavaScript you again have basically two options

1. Use the `QObject` signal mechanism
2. Pass a JavaScript callback to C++ and invoke from there

Qt's asnychronous QML API is usually done with the former, but if you prefer the latter, have a look at `QJSValue` as the C++ data type to use for the callback argument.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I just want to summarize for those who will search for the same solution.

There are at least 2 ways to do that:

- Emit signal from C++ object when task done.
- Pass JS function to C++ which will be called when task done.

***Test C++ object declaration:***

```cpp
class MyItem : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyItem(QObject *parent = 0);
    Q_INVOKABLE void someAsyncFunc();
    Q_INVOKABLE void someAnotherAsyncFunc(QJSValue value);

signals:
    void someAsyncFuncFinished();
};
```

***Test C++ object implementation:***

```cpp
MyItem::MyItem(QObject *parent) :
QObject(parent) {}

void MyItem::someAsyncFunc()
{
    // do some work here
    emit someAsyncFuncFinished();
}

void MyItem::someAnotherAsyncFunc(QJSValue value) {
    // do some work here
    if (value.isCallable()) {
        value.call();
    }
}
```

***Registering custom item as a singleton:***

```cpp
static QObject *my_singleton_provider(QQmlEngine *engine, QJSEngine *scriptEngine)
{
    Q_UNUSED(engine)
    Q_UNUSED(scriptEngine)
    static MyItem *item = nullptr;
    if(!item)
        item = new MyItem();
    return item;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterSingletonType<MyItem>("Qt.MyTest", 1, 0, "MyItem", my_singleton_provider);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    return app.exec();
}
```

And so QML files to test it:

***1. Signal fired when task finished***

```js
Item {
    id: testItem

    function func1()
    {
        console.log("func1 executing...")
        MyItem.someAsyncFuncFinished.connect(func2);
        MyItem.someAsyncFunc();
    }

    function func2()
    {
        console.log("func2 executing...")
    }

    Component.onCompleted: func1();
}
```

***2. Passing JS function to C++:***

```js
Item {
    id: testItem

    function func1()
    {
        console.log("func1 executing...")
        MyItem.someAnotherAsyncFunc(func2);
    }

    function func2()
    {
        console.log("func2 executing...")
    }

    Component.onCompleted: func1();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about QML and I think in normal JavaScript your code should work. But I can suggest you this ugly way if its not calling sequentially:

```
function fun1() {
    ImageReader.magic(photo);
    return 1;
}
function fun2(wait){
    if(wait==1)
    {
        myImg.source = ""; 
        myImg.source = "image://ImageReader";
    }
}
fun2(fun1());
```

Comment: Thanks. But it still does not work. `ImageReader.magic(photo);` is a function written in C++ by inheriting QImageProvider, which takes a longer time to process the image and gives back to QML.